# Laptop power usage explanation

Tags: laptop, cpu, gpu, power-management

I have an ASUS ROG STRIX G15.

I've killed most of the ASUS software, and am using Throttlestop to control CPU usage.

- I've undervolted by 75mv
- I've set the display to 60Hz (rather than the 144Hz it is capable of)
- I've set brightness to minimum
- I've removed all peripherals.
- I have 2 M.2 SSD and no spinning drives

Throttlestop reports the CPU package as using 2watts of power, and the GPU is inactive.

Yet Throttlestop still reports the **total power usage** as around **35watts**, which means my battery only lasts just over an hour. Setting brightness to max increases power usage by 10watts. The screenshot below shows it bursting to 55watts of usage when I changed to the Performance profile. Battery profile reports 35-40watts of usage.

**How can I find what is using the power?**

[image: Screenshot of Throttlestop, GPU and display settings]

Comment: how old is the battery? it's possible that lithium cells are not storing the max amount either because is old or defective. have u contacted the asus support yet?

Comment: @DarkBeccio only about 6-months, and has always been set to 80% max charge (except when I go out and about). Wh rating of the battery from Throttlestop looks good (61.688 at 80%). Not spoken to Asus support, can't imagine them being very useful.